# A word for 'related in managerial way'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for "related in work-related way"? I want to include owners, managers and the like.

Here's an example: I want to convey "This is a list of all owners, managers, administrators, etc...." with a word that would fill this blank: "This is a list of all ________-related workers". ('-related' can be removed).

Comment: Perhaps *stakeholder*? -  "a person with an interest or concern in something, especially a business".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common expression for a group of people like that would be "upper management"

Comment: I want to up-vote your answer, but don't have enough rep yet...hopefully soon. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

"This is a list of all managerial staff."

*managerial staff* is a very common construction.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'stakeholders' is far too wide a definition, as it could apply to customers, suppliers and many more. Conversely, a word which just refers to management does not necessarily encompass owners. I think you need to give more background information about the purpose of the list to get an appropriate answer. You may need to use more than one word.